# Is converting my server response char array to a wchar_t array the correct way to handle the server message my client receives?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

I am new to c++, windows programming, and these forums(sorry for any breach of procedure) and after some time I have not been able to track down an answer for this so here goes...

I am writing a little chat program, which currently comprises a server that sits around waiting for a client to connect and when a client connects it sends the message "You have connected!". The client is a Win32 application that automatically connects to the server, receives the connection message, and stuffs it in a multi-line text box.

I have it working but I had to use some code to convert the server response to a wchar_t, and the way I am doing it doesn't feel right to me. Is there a better way to set up either the client or the server, or is the way I am doing it correct?

Here is the relevant server code...

```
    ...
    //JMP_:sListen and sConnect are both = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

    if(sConnect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen)){
        cout << "A connection was found" << endl;
        send(sConnect,"You have connected!", 20, NULL);
    }
    ...
```

Here is the bit of code where I declare the char array for the server response...

```
    ...
    // includes up here

    char serverresponse[255];

    // WinMain down here
    ...
```

and the bit of code that recieves the message from the server...

```
    ...
    //JMP_: this is in the WinMain function.

    connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
recv(sConnect, serverresponse, sizeof(serverresponse), NULL);
getchar();
    ...
```

This last bit of code is where I put the server response into the text box...

```
    ...
    // JMP_: this is in WndProc

    case WM_CREATE:
        {
         // Create an edit box
        hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, _T("EDIT"),
            NULL,
            WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL |
            ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
            50, 100, 200, 100,
            hWnd,
            (HMENU) ID_EDITCHILD,
            (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),NULL);

        //JMP_: I just pulled this indented bit from MSDN
            // Convert to a wchar_t*  
            size_t origsize = strlen(serverresponse) + 1;
            const size_t newsize = 100;
            size_t convertedChars = 0;
            wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
            mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, serverresponse, _TRUNCATE);
        //

        // Add text to the window. 
        SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0,  (LPARAM) wcstring);

        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Is there something in particular you are coincerned about?

Comment: I am just concerned or confused about why I have to convert it.  I don't understand why there isn't a SendMessage that takes a char array.

Comment: There is. SendMessage is a macro that expands to either SendMessageA or SendMessageW, so assuming you have only valid ascii text (and not UTF-8), you can use SendMessgeA().

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have to convert the server response to a wchar_t is because you build your client code as a Unicode build, and subsequently all your api calls that are made to windows that expect any from of car* or wchar* are #ifdef'd on unicode, The conventional names are replaced by the preprocessor with names ending in either W (for unicode) or A for non Unicode. Just as Mats Peterson pointed out. So what happens is when you stuff your data into a char* array from the call to recv, you'll have to convert it to wchar_t to display it in a text box or any other windows UI control. It is 'ok' to use the narrow character api's in a unicode project ( as windows will just covert it over to being Unicode for you behind the scenes ), but can cause some potential performance issues if done in quick succession.